# Spring AOP gives IllegalArgumentException with Java 8

Tags: java, spring, jetty, spring-aop

With Java 8 and Spring AOP 4.0.6 I am getting following error

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning file MonitorAroundPerformance.class
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseDir(AnnotationParser.java:705)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseDir(AnnotationParser.java:686)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseDir(AnnotationParser.java:686)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseDir(AnnotationParser.java:686)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseDir(AnnotationParser.java:686)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseDir(AnnotationParser.java:686)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parse(AnnotationParser.java:821)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$ParserTask.call(AnnotationConfiguration.java:159)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$1.run(AnnotationConfiguration.java:531)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:607)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:536)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.scanClass(AnnotationParser.java:970)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseDir(AnnotationParser.java:700)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseDir(AnnotationParser.java:686)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseDir(AnnotationParser.java:686)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseDir(AnnotationParser.java:686)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseDir(AnnotationParser.java:686)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseDir(AnnotationParser.java:686)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parse(AnnotationParser.java:821)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$ParserTask.call(AnnotationConfiguration.java:159)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$1.run(AnnotationConfiguration.java:531)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:607)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:536)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

However when I change Java Source and target to 1.7 , then this error goes away.
POM.xml settings -

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.6.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Jars in build path in Eclipse Kepler - spring-aop-4.0.6 , aspectjrt-1.8.2.jar, aopalliance-1.0.jar, jetty-maven-plugin:9.1.1.v20140108

Config:

```
<bean id="performanceAdvice"
    class="com.util.MonitorAroundPerformance" />

<bean id="performanceAdvisor"
    class="org.springframework.aop.support.RegexpMethodPointcutAdvisor"
    depends-on="propertyOverrideConfigurer">
    <property name="advice" ref="performanceAdvice" />
</bean>


<bean
    class="org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator">
    <property name="proxyTargetClass" value="true" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Jetty 9.2.0 is the first version of Jetty to support annotation and class scanning for JDK8](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.2.3.v20140905/VERSION.txt#L204-L205).

There was an update to the asm library we use, along with some api changes to support the new JDK8 bytecode scanning.

You'll want to upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

If just upgrading to asm 5.* doesn't work for you, exclude all asm jars from jetty as well.
This configuration worked for me:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.6.v20170531</version>
            <configuration>
                <webApp>
                    <webInfIncludeJarPattern>.*/^(asm-all-repackaged)[^/]*\.jar$</webInfIncludeJarPattern>
                </webApp>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
                    <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
                    <version>5.2</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
                    <artifactId>asm-commons</artifactId>
                    <version>5.2</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similiar problem with GWT 2.8 web project (eclipse plugin, JAVA 8).

My simple solution was to create GWT web project in a new eclipse workspace.